# OnCollision player colliding with any object

Tags: c#, xna

I am creating a 2D platformer using farseer physics engine, I am having the hardest of times trying to figure out how to use OnCollision, even though I saw [this](https://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/discussions/283336), I am still trying to grasp the concept. This is what I am working [with](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7qIyJg4xV0).  I want to know when the player is hitting ground so I can have a bool that is called isJumping. When the player is jumping, isJumping is true so that the player does not keep jumping.
(I also want to have a ground bool that will say, "hay your on the ground".)

The problem with this code is that I will get a null reference. I am also only detecting the floor object, do I need to some how detected the other items that I put on screen as well as the floor object?

```
public bool OnCollision(Fixture fixtureA, Fixture fixtureB,  FarseerPhysics.Dynamics.Contacts.Contact contact)
    {
        if (contact.IsTouching())
        {
            if (fixtureA.Body.GetType() == Person.GetType() & fixtureB.Body.GetType() == game1.floor.GetType())
            {
                ground = true;
                isJumping = false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

1. What I am trying to do with this code is first,find out if player is touching ground, not hitting its head or hitting the left or right wall of an object. (also to make it a check if player can jump)
2. If I add more object to the game will I have to add more code to this function even though I only want it to detect if player's bottom collides with object, make player stop?
3. I should be able to detect if the player is colliding with its top or sides as well, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach to determine if the player is in air is to use Ray Casting.

For example, I use a method like this to determine what object the ray collided with (note: RayCastResult is just a class that holds the results):

```
    public static RayCastResult FindClosest(this World world, Vector2 startPoint, Vector2 endPoint, Func<Fixture, bool> filter)
    {
        var result = new RayCastResult ();

        world.RayCast((f, p, n, fr) =>
        {
            if (filter(f)) {
                return -1.0f;
            }

            result.Fixture = f;
            result.HitPoint = p;
            result.HitPointSurfaceNormal = n;
            return fr;
        }, startPoint, endPoint);

        return result;
    }
```

Depending on what you return inside RayCast callback function you can do these things with Ray Casting:

1. return -1 in your callback fixture then the fixture is going to be ignored and the ray will  continue (useful to ignore certain objects as demonstrated above)
2. return 0 the ray will terminate (this will return the first fixture that is encountered, but that might not be the closest object as the collision engine doesn't necessarily process collisions in that order)
3. return fraction then the ray will stop at this point (this is what is used above to eventually find the closest object)
4. return 1 then the ray will continue until it ends (you could use this to get a list of all fixtures the ray collides with)

Farseer Ray Casting engine is based on Box2D's engine which is very well [documented over here](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082976)

The above method can then be used in this way to determine if an object is in air (which involves a bit of magic numbers as you can't get a 100% accuracy). In my case I am casting a ray from the centre of a circle and then checking if the ray casting encountered any object in proximity of the circle:

```
    private bool RunInAirHitTest(Vector2 start, Vector2 end)
    {
        var hitTest = _world.FindClosest (start, end, f => IsHit(f.Body));
        var hitDistance = (hitTest.HitPoint - start).Length ();
        return !hitTest.HitOccurred || hitDistance > _wheelRadius * 1.2f;
    }
```